# How do I block YouTube (et al.) on Windows 10 from being able to cast to smart TV?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, youtube, smart-tv

Someone in my household recently bought a smart TV and YouTube is somehow able to allow me to cast to it, which I'm confident I'll never need to do from my PC. Thus, I'm trying to figure out how to block this connection from the PC end for YouTube and any other site that uses a similar casting system.

So far I have tried:

1. Disabling Network discovery
   [Network Discovery disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8qBT.png)
2. Confirming that Windows Media Player Network Sharing Service is off
   [service is off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwiN6.png)
3. Even disabling Bluetooth

Another aspect of this problem is I'm not sure by which system/protocol YouTube is able to find and stream to the TV, otherwise I'd have an idea of what to disable in Wifi Properties ([this window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXSv3.png)).

It's not a problem if the solution prevents my PC from ever seeing any other device on a shared network.

Also, this is my first question so apologies if it has issues, and thank you to anyone who has any suggestions!

Comment: I don't believe this relies on any of the services you note. Is the Smart TV connected to the same network, or does it broadcast a wireless display signal?

Comment: Further, have you done any research on this subject?

Comment: Yes I found that the things that I tried didn't disable the "Cast to TV" option.

Comment: Regarding if I've done research: I tried to find by what mechanism/system/protocol/etc the connection between the TV and my PC is being established, but had a hard time finding relevant info on that on google. My main point of confusion is how the PC is able to connect if I disabled Network Discovery. I'll read up on Network Discovery to learn more, and try to find other approaches to achieve my main goal. Also thank you for responding!

Comment: Network Discovery is an internal Microsoft system used to find various common, and is very probably not what Youtube uses.